# App crashes with 'NoClassDefFoundError' only on Android 4.x

Tags: android

I am getting a series of this type or error while running my project: https://github.com/evercam/evercam-play-android on lower Android versions (Tested on HTC One X - 4.1.1 && Galaxy S3 - 4.3 simulators and both crashes). But it works on Android 5.

Seems all of the crashes are happening when creating Runnable object, but I couldn't figure out the reason. I've resolved a few other similar crashes by removing the runnables but new error always come up.

Any idea what could be going wrong here? Thanks a lot!

I am using Android Studio 1.3 and here is the logs with the latest error:

```
08-05 05:28:51.071    3080-3080/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'io.evercam.androidapp.custom.CameraLayout$3', referenced from method io.evercam.androidapp.custom.CameraLayout.<init>
08-05 05:28:51.071    3080-3080/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 6631 (Lio/evercam/androidapp/custom/CameraLayout$3;) in Lio/evercam/androidapp/custom/CameraLayout;
08-05 05:28:51.071    3080-3080/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0019
08-05 05:28:51.071    3080-3080/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lio/evercam/androidapp/custom/GradientTitleLayout;)
08-05 05:28:51.071    3080-3080/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'io.evercam.androidapp.custom.CameraLayout$2', referenced from method io.evercam.androidapp.custom.CameraLayout.showOfflineIcon
08-05 05:28:51.071    3080-3080/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 6630 (Lio/evercam/androidapp/custom/CameraLayout$2;) in Lio/evercam/androidapp/custom/CameraLayout;
08-05 05:28:51.071    3080-3080/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0005
08-05 05:28:51.071    3080-3080/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method io.evercam.androidapp.custom.GradientTitleLayout.getOfflineImageView, referenced from method io.evercam.androidapp.custom.CameraLayout.getOfflineIconBounds
08-05 05:28:51.071    3080-3080/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 44814: Lio/evercam/androidapp/custom/GradientTitleLayout;.getOfflineImageView ()Landroid/widget/ImageView;
08-05 05:28:51.071    3080-3080/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0007
08-05 05:28:51.075    3080-3080/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method io.evercam.androidapp.custom.GradientTitleLayout.removeGradientShadow, referenced from method io.evercam.androidapp.custom.CameraLayout.showThumbnail
08-05 05:28:51.075    3080-3080/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 44815: Lio/evercam/androidapp/custom/GradientTitleLayout;.removeGradientShadow ()V
08-05 05:28:51.075    3080-3080/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0057
08-05 05:28:51.075    3080-3080/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method io.evercam.androidapp.custom.GradientTitleLayout.setTitle, referenced from method io.evercam.androidapp.custom.CameraLayout.updateTitleIfDifferent
08-05 05:28:51.075    3080-3080/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 44816: Lio/evercam/androidapp/custom/GradientTitleLayout;.setTitle (Ljava/lang/String;)V
08-05 05:28:51.075    3080-3080/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0028
08-05 05:28:51.075    3080-3080/? D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xaeaa at 0x1b in Lio/evercam/androidapp/custom/CameraLayout;.<init>
08-05 05:28:51.075    3080-3080/? D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xaf0d at 0xdf in Lio/evercam/androidapp/custom/CameraLayout;.<init>
08-05 05:28:51.075    3080-3080/? D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xaea8 at 0x105 in Lio/evercam/androidapp/custom/CameraLayout;.<init>
08-05 05:28:51.075    3080-3080/? D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xaea9 at 0x07 in Lio/evercam/androidapp/custom/CameraLayout;.showOfflineIcon
08-05 05:28:51.075    3080-3080/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-05 05:28:51.075    3080-3080/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4b68648)
08-05 05:28:52.767    3080-3104/io.evercam.androidapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 778K, 7% free 12359K/13164K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
08-05 05:28:54.083    3080-3080/io.evercam.androidapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.evercam.androidapp.custom.CameraLayout$3
            at io.evercam.androidapp.custom.CameraLayout.<init>(CameraLayout.java:256)
            at io.evercam.androidapp.CamerasActivity.addAllCameraViews(CamerasActivity.java:439)
            at io.evercam.androidapp.CamerasActivity$1.run(CamerasActivity.java:123)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 05:31:12.083    3080-3080/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 3080 SIG: 9
```

Comment: what is minimumsdkversion

Comment: @KaranMer It's Android 14, here is my build.gradle: https://github.com/evercam/evercam-play-android/blob/master/evercamPlay/build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was I didn't implement Multidex completely, it's the same problem with [NoClassDefFoundError with Android Studio on Android 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698287/noclassdeffounderror-with-android-studio-on-android-4)

After setting `multiDexEnabled = true` in defaultConfig, there are more changes need to be made:

1. Include `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` in build.gradle
2. Make the Application class extend `MultiDexApplication` instead of just Application.

Answer (score 0):

[Please, check this issue](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17), basically, a renaming of lib to libs in dependencies. From the error shown, [this problem](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) is ocurring because the class file is not present or could not be loaded, check if `Lio/evercam/androidapp/custom/GradientTitleLayout` present

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)  But my dependencies are in 'libs' folder already: https://github.com/evercam/evercam-play-android/tree/master/evercamPlay/libs , and the class that not found does not belong to dependencies at all..

Comment: @Liuting [try this then](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349244/could-not-find-method-xxx-referenced-from-method-yyy). Without additional info, we cant be of specific aid. From the Logs, you have issues with the `io.evercam` I suggest using [ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) to read all packages in the device, and check if its correctly installed/running